# Embedding Maven 3

Tags: maven-3

Is there any sort of documentation on the topic, except of m2eclipse sources?

Thanks.
JBaruch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, the documentation for [Maven Embedder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0-alpha-5/maven-embedder/) has still to be created (yes, the [Maven+3.0.x](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.0.x) page created by Jason does mention a link to the old documentation but Jason wrote later in [MNG-3658](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3658) that the documentation has to be created).

I'm afraid your best options will be m2eclipse or NetBeans sources right now.