# Lightweight runtime "build system"

Tags: java, dependencies

I've recently worked on refactoring a system that processes bundles of client data.  The system executes a series of steps, each of which consumes files from previous steps (and sometime in-memory data), and produces its own output, in the form of files or data.  Sometimes the output data for a particular step is already available.  I have to be careful to make sure that, when one step fails, we continue to run all possible steps (ones that don't depend on the failed step), so that the final output is as complete as possible.  Furthermore, not all steps have to be run in all situations.

Previously, the relationships were all implicit in the structure of the code.  For instance:

```
void processClientData() {
    try {
        processA();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "exception occured in step A", e);
        processC(); // C doesn't depend on A, so we can still run it.
        throw e;
    }

    processB();
    processC();
    //etc... for ~20 steps
}
```

I changed this to make the dependencies explicit, the error handling uniform, etc, by introducing Tasks:

```
public interface Task {
    List<Task> getDependencies();
    void execute(); //only called after all dependencies have been executed
}

public class TaskRunner {
    public void run(Set<Task> targets) {
        // run the dependencies and targets ala ANT
        // make sure to run all possible tasks on the "road" to targets
        // ...
    }
}
```

This starts to feel a lot like a very watered-down version of a build system with dependency management (ANT, being most familiar to me).  I don't want to pull in ANT for this kind of thing, and I certainly don't want to write out the XML.

I have my system up and running (mostly), but it still feels a bit hacked together, and I have since reflected on how much I hate to be reinventing the wheel.  I would expect that this is a fairly common problem - one that has been solved many times over by people smarter than me.  Alas, a few hours of googling turned up nothing

Is there a library that implements this sort of thing, without being a really heavy-weight build system?  I'd also appreciate any pointers, including libraries in other languages (or even novel systems) that I should take inspiration from.

EDIT: I appreciate the suggestions (and I will give them due consideration), but I'm really NOT looking for a "build system" per se.  What I am looking for is something more like the *kernel* of a build system, that I could just call directly from Java and use as a small, low-overhead library for doing said dependency analysis, task execution, and resulting resource management.  Like I said, I have existing (working) code in pure Java, and I don't want to bring in XML and all of the baggage that comes with it, without a **very** compelling reason.

Comment: define *heavy-weight*, I use Maven 3.x and only Maven 3.x on even the smallest projects. I even write my own plugins for other non-Java languages. It is much more **lightweight** than maintaining my own implementations of all the rich features and capabilities it provides?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Ant?

Comment: Essentially, this is a very high-throughput and tightly integrated part of the system - I won't want to go from a very low-overhead, but hard to maintain system, to one that has much higher overhead, both conceptually and performance-wise.  Besides, if I have to tell the other devs that we now have to maintain business logic in XML, I may also have to start sleeping with one eye open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jsr166 fork/join framework. It seems to me this is exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html

This is included in JDK7 but is available as a separate jar for 5 and 6. If I wasn't on my tablet I'd write a more comprehensive example. Maybe someone else can expand in the meantime.

```
public class DependencyTreeTask extends RecursiveAction {

  private final List<DependencyTreeTask> dependencies = new ArrayList<Task>();

  public void addDependency(DependencyTreeTask t) { dependencies.add(t) }

  public void compute() {
    invokeAll(dependencies);
  }

}

...
// build tree...
DependencyTreeTask root = ...
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
pool.invoke(root);
```

You also have to take care if your graph is unconnected, but there are a well known set of algorithms for determining this.

Comment: It looks to me like that makes the parallelism part (which isn't strictly necessary anyway) a bit easier / cleaner, but after skimming the documentation you linked, I didn't see anything that can help with dependency management - not that I think it's particularly hard.  Did I miss something?

Comment: ForkJoinTasks (also look as subclasses) inherently manage dependencies  through the fork (invokeAll ...) and join constructs.  It wouldn't be hard to build a simple dependency tree and submit the root object to the pool for execution.  The parallel portion is "free" from the framework, and of course not strictly necessary (with a pool of size 1).  You essentially get the topological sort from your tree as part of these constructs.

Answer (score 2):

At its core, a build system does 3 things. It manages dependency, it test whether something is "built" or not, and it "builds" the things that aren't built.

Dependency management is little more than a simple topological sort. There rest is iterating through the tasks in dependent order, and processing them.

You can readily create something like:

```
BuildSystem bs = new BuildSystem();
bs.addTask(new Task1());
bs.addTask(new Task...);
bs.addTask(new TaskN());

bs.build();

public void build() {
    List<Task> sortedTasks = topologicalTaskSort(tasks);
    for(Task t : sortedTasks) {
        if (t.needsBuilding()) {
            t.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

If you have no need to externalize the list of Tasks, then there's no reason for an XML file or anything.

The topological sort allows you to simply add tasks to the list and let the system sort things out. Not a problem with 4 tasks, more of an issue with dozens of tasks.

The sort fails if it detects a cycle of dependency, so that's where you get that control.

Something like this is "too simple" to need a framework. I don't know how you're doing your dependency management now.

Comment: It sounds like there aren't any common libraries that handle this, and only this, without the bloat of a full build system.  Currently, I'm doing the topological sort implicitly via recursion - perhaps explicitly separating that out will make it seems less hacky.  Plus, I appreciate the effort that went into writing this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: There's actually, I think, a Ruby (maybe its Groovy) build system, which uses, you know, Ruby. And it could be run within JRuby -- but that's, basically, overkill. So, not really worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider writing a Maven plugin, it isn't that hard and much **lighter weight** because you only have to provide the relevant special logic. All the infrastructure is provided by Maven. Maven 3 would even give you things like parallel builds where your plugin supports it for free, amongst all the other things it provides.

One of the major goals of Maven 3 was a re-write to make it as easy as possible to **embed** the workflow engine in your own projects.

Comment: I would actually say the opposite - I find that Maven is usually several times slower than ANT, and thus has greater overhead (above the build logic it executes), and thus (by my reckoning) is significantly heavier-weight.  Also, see the EDIT in the question.

Comment: no one is talking about speed, my point is **lightweight** is subjective, to me it means I have to do as little as possible to get a result, to you it is about speed. With his edit, I still think a Maven plugin is the path of least resistance and the least amount of work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  You make a very good point that light-weight can be subjective.  For the record, I typically have a joint definition for light-weight: both conceptually small (probably less than 10K LOC), and fast.

Comment: For anyone stumbling here, here is a relevant question: [Embedding Maven 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3333251/150762).  For the moment, it appears to be somewhat of a dead end (little documentation), but this may (hopefully) change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of Jenkins being used for this sort of thing in addition to it's primary 'build system' role. I only just started using Jenkins so can't say for sure whether it will do what you need. I'm impressed with it so far. It's relatively easy to use and has a lot of configuration options. There are a large number of plugins for it as well. Just run Jenkins and go to the plugins page to review the list and install them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reminds me of [iwant](http://iwant.fluentjava.org), a java build engine I've been developing. You can declare your target definitions with dependencies using fluent java, and in addition to using it normally from a commandline (or ant script), you can also embed your build in a java program.